# I can't acces from my Host (Win10) to my Guest (CentOS7) via VNC

Tags: centos, virtualbox, vnc

I have done first `yum -y install tigervnc-server` Then `vncpasswd` in order to set a password to vnc. Then I have started the vncserver on my guest with `vncserver :1 -geometry 800x600 -depth 24`, even you can see in the picture that the server is up:

[image]

And when I go to Windows 10 to connect with UltraVNC Viewer and I type the Host-Only IP the program says to me `failed to connect to server` even connecting with port (5901) or with display (1).

Comment: Firewall? SE-Linux?

Comment: @rdupz I was following this: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=x&f=3 and didn't say nothing about. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @rdupz I have done `selinux=disabled` in `etc/selinux/config` and `systemctl disable firewalld`. It doesn't work yet. It is needed to reboot the system or kill and recreate the vncserver? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `selinux=disabled` in `etc/selinux/config` and `systemctl disable firewalld` reboot and it works.